# store the text into session storage when user types something

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I am using the following in my react form (formik library) to display a text field.

How can I store the value of the text field in sessionstorage as soon as user finishes typing something in the text field? had it been a select, I would have added `Onclick` function to store the selection into session storage.

```
import {Button, InputLabel,Menu,MenuItem, Select, TextField, TextareaAutosize} from '@material-ui/core'
import {styled} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)( {
    width: '50%',
})

const CustomTextField = ({
                             placeholder,
                             ...props
                         }) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField(props);
    const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";
    return (
        <div>
            <InputLabel>{placeholder}</InputLabel>
            <StyledTextField
                {...field}
                helperText={errorText}
                error={!!errorText}
            />
        </div>
    );
};



<CustomTextField name = "textDescription" type ="text" placeholder="Text Description"/>
```

The reason I want t ostore it in storage is because I am using [file upload (advanced)](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/fileupload) version and as soon as user clicks on `upload` button, I want to grab the description from storage and use it in the api call.

After typing something, I tried using the following:

```
  console.log("Printing Document By getElementbyID value");
            console.log(document.getElementById('textDescription').value);
```

But it keeps on printing `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

**Troubleshooting results based on Bassam Rubaye's answer:**

Added an event like this:

```
<StyledTextField
                    {...field}
                    helperText={errorText}
                    error={!!errorText}
                    onChange={handleChange}  
                />
```

And tried the following:

```
 const handleChange = e => {
        
        console.log("Value of Description");
        console.log(e.target.value);
        
    }
```

It is printing like the following in `console.log`:

```
Value of Description
t
Value of Description
te
Value of Description
tes
Value of Description
test
```

Is it going to store `test` in the session storage?

Comment: Would either onChange or onBlur event handler help with your case?

Comment: @Y.S. how would both are going to work, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why don't you just save the info to state instead of session storage using onChange, then access the state value when you upload the file?

Comment: @Jake Yes, I was thinking about that as storing in sessionstorage seems like a hassle. but my JS file where I am working on doesn't have a class. Should I try using hooks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure about your use case, but You can add a handler for "onChange" event on the StyledTextField, and inside that handler, you can add the value of that component to the sessionStorage

```
handleChange(e) {
 /** you will need to throttle the call here as well
     to avoid calling setItem with each change but only calling it after for example 300MS to make sure the user has completed typing
 */
 sessionStorage.setItem("yourKey", e.target.value);
```

}

Comment: Could you please elaborate   on `//you will need to throttle the call here as well` ?

Comment: Also, I added the results of your approach in my post by editing it. Please take a look. I am wondering if it will store `test` in session storage and is everything looks correct?

Comment: I added a comment on why you will need to throttle setItem so that to avoid calling it before the user finished typing

Comment: yes sessionStorage.setItem() will replace the value of the key if the key is already has a value , so in your case it should has test as the last value